# Printing multiple empty variables as "Not Available" with a specific style

Tags: php

I'm trying to print the value of empty variables as "Not available" with a specific style (class = 'not-available'). The data will be taken from multiple custom fields and some of them may have an empty value. I'm already doing this with the following code in PHP. My question: is there any alternative way to do the same more efficiently without checking each variable separately?

```
$na = "<span class='not-available'>Not available</span>";

$prog_auth_id = get_field('prog_auth_id');
if(empty($prog_auth_id)) $prog_auth_id = $na;

$prog_entity_cat = get_field('prog_entity_cat');
if(empty($prog_entity_cat)) $prog_entity_cat = $na;

$prog_assoc_entity = get_field('prog_assoc_entity');
if(empty($prog_assoc_entity)) $prog_assoc_entity = $na;
```

Comment: Hint: Any time you're repeating similar code, you have an opportunity to use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in a loop to identify the variables that are  empty or not and style them as desired:

```
$fields = ['prog_auth_id', 'prog_entity_cat', 'prog_assoc_entity'];
foreach($fields as $value) {
    $$value = (empty($$value)) ? $na : $$value;
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/gWp7o)

Comment: great, happy I could help!